# How to log ruby mechanize post request?

Tags: ruby, logging

I have a code

```
@agent = Mechanize.new do |a| 
  a.log = Logger.new(File.open("logs/parser.log", "w")),
  a.ssl_version, 
  a.verify_mode = 'SSLv3', 
  OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE, 
  a.user_agent_alias = 'Windows Mozilla'
end
def authorization
  ajax_headers = { 'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest', 'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
   'Accept' => 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip, deflate',
   'Referer' => 'http://mysite.ru/' }
  params = {'login' => 'name', 'domain' => 'mail.ru', 'password' => 'pass'}
  response = @agent.post( 'http://mydomain', params, ajax_headers)
end
```

This code case an error

```
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mechanize-2.6.0/lib/mechanize.rb:1264:in `post_form': undefined method `debug' for
<Array:0x2d20610> (NoMethodError)
```

Without a.log = Logger.new(File.open("logs/parser.log", "w")), everything is working fine, so it cases an error. 
How to log my post request correct in this case?

Comment: Can you post all error text?